# CakePHP CRUD, Add action throwing "Call to a member function format on string"

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3.5.14 with

- friendsofcake/crud 5.3.3
- and friendsofcake/crud-view 0.10.0

I've been struggling to get the "Add" action to work.
It is throwing the following error in `/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php`

> Call to a member function format() on string

on line 2785.

```
$out = $widget->render($data, $this->context());
```

Expanded Arguments:

```
[
        'formatter' => null,
        'prepend' => null,
        'append' => null,
        'inline' => null,
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'required' => false,
        'options' => null,
        'tooltip' => null,
        'templateVars' => [],
        'id' => 'created',
        'second' => false,
        'name' => 'created',
        'val' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        'year' => [
            'required' => false,
            'order' => 'desc'
        ],
        'month' => [
            'required' => false,
            'names' => true
        ],
        'day' => [
            'required' => false
        ],
        'hour' => [
            'required' => false,
            'format' => (int) 24
        ],
        'minute' => [
            'required' => false,
            'interval' => (int) 1,
            'round' => null
        ],
        'meridian' => [
            'required' => false
        ]
    ]
    object(Cake\View\Form\EntityContext) {
        [protected] _request => object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest) {
            params => [
                [maximum depth reached]
            ]
            data => [[maximum depth reached]]
            query => [[maximum depth reached]]
            cookies => [
                [maximum depth reached]
            ]
            url => 'users/add'
            base => ''
            webroot => '/'
            here => '/users/add'
            trustProxy => false
            [protected] _environment => [
                [maximum depth reached]
            ]
            [protected] _input => null
            [protected] _detectors => [
                [maximum depth reached]
            ]
            [protected] _detectorCache => [
                [maximum depth reached]
            ]
            [protected] stream => object(Zend\Diactoros\PhpInputStream) {}
            [protected] uri => object(Zend\Diactoros\Uri) {}
            [protected] session => object(Cake\Network\Session) {}
            [protected] attributes => [[maximum depth reached]]
            [protected] emulatedAttributes => [
                [maximum depth reached]
            ]
            [protected] uploadedFiles => [[maximum depth reached]]
            [protected] protocol => null
            [protected] requestTarget => null
        }
        [protected] _context => [
            'entity' => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {},
            'table' => null,
            'validator' => []
        ]
        [protected] _rootName => 'Users'
        [protected] _isCollection => false
        [protected] _tables => [
            'Users' => object(App\Model\Table\UsersTable) {}
        ]
        [protected] _validator => [
            '' => object(Cake\Validation\Validator) {}
        ]
    }
```

I've tried to change various things in my Database directly but couldn't get any reliable results
(Sometimes I got to the "Add" page after removing the '`DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP`' but get an invalid timestamp format instead, but couldn't reproduce the behaviour in a second test)

This is what my Users table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

which is being created by this migration

```
$this->table('Users')
            ->addColumn('name', 'string', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 25,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->addColumn('email', 'string', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 45,
                'null' => true,
            ])
            ->addColumn('password', 'string', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 65,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->addColumn('created', 'timestamp', [
                'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
                'limit' => null,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->addColumn('modified', 'timestamp', [
                'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
                'update' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
                'limit' => null,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->create();
```

My controllers are are basically empty

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{

}
```

Since I've done is follow the Crud and crud-view getting started guides.
I'm kind of stuck at this point and would appreciate any help on this.

For reference, here are pastebins of the full files:
[Migratoin 20180406144732_Initial.php](https://pastebin.com/aQRrryTX)
[AppController.php](https://pastebin.com/9ZrAkWNk)
[Stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/ddyChpjP)
[Complete Composer show output](https://pastebin.com/E4d8FPX8)

If I'm missing any information, let me know.
*Thanks and regards,

Minzkraut*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* CakePHP expects those fields to be datetime fields, not timestamp. If you change that, it should work as expected.

As well, while you can certainly set the default/update values, since it's timestamp, you'll need to change those or just let the CakePHP ORM handle them via the [`TimestampBehavior`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html).

Comment: If I change my field to 'datetime' I get  SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '04/09/2018 6:54 AM' for column 'created' at row 1